# Display popup when class elements are clicked using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onclick, echo

So I am trying to get this code to echo my popup when class elements are clicked. I have the code in the head section of my wordpress file but it's not working. Any ideas?

I've even tried moving the variable around and still nothing

```
    <?php

function popCash() {
$doit = "<script type='text/javascript'>
var wid = '111111';
var uid = '111111';
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.popcash.net/pop.js'></script>";

echo $doit;
}
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.post-thumbnail, .thumb-block, .display-img').click(function(){

        var <?php echo popCash;?>

        });
    });
</script>
```

I need it to show the popup when the class elements are clicked

Comment: `echo` is a PHP statement, not JS, and will not work in the manner you expect. You would get more constructive help if you described the issue you're trying to solve, as I can guarantee you there is a better way to do it

Comment: The issue I'm trying to solve is to get the var popCash to execute when the following class elements are clicked: .post-thumbnail, .thumb-block, .display-img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what kind of result you want, you need to use `console.log(popCash)` or `alert(popCash)`, not `echo`, which is not valid JavaScript.

**Follow-up after comment:**

If you're trying to execute that script, it's more like `document.write(popCash)` that you'd be looking for, but this wouldn't be a very efficient way to accomplish what you're trying to do because you'd be loading up that script every single time you got a click, and accumulating additional `<script>` elements with every click.

For one thing, it looks like you're assigning values to global variables `wid` and `uid` using a script. There's absolutely no good reason to create a new script just to do that. Simply assign the variable directly:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var wid;
var uid;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.post-thumbnail, .thumb-block, .display-img').click(function(){

    wid = '111111';
    uid = '111111';

    var popCash = "<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.popcash.net/pop.js'>\n"+
                "<\/script>";
        document.write(popCash);
    });
});
</script>
```

But then the question becomes: "Why reload the 'cdn.popcash.net' for every click?"

Isn't there a method inside the script that can be called whenever it needs to be invoked again?

And even if the script is so poorly written that it must be run from the top for every invocation (that's a terrible API!), you can at least dynamically create and delete script tags to do the job instead of using `document.write()`, but that would take a bit more explaining to describe.

Comment: I just want the script in the variable to execute when the class elements are clicked.

Comment: I've posted a follow-up above.

Comment: Basically, google has been cracking down on the popups when anywhere on the screen is clicked. So, I'm just trying to execute the popup when certain classes (specifically images) are clicked. I only want it to execute the script once for each user. Not when it is clicked everytime. I'll post my new code (still doesn't work) but I tried placing the popup script in php and called it in javascript.

Comment: I have edited my code if you want to take a look :)

Comment: `var <?php echo popCash;?>` doesn't make any sense. You have a PHP function called `popCash`, which would require parentheses to invoke, but even if you invoke it correctly, the output it produces wouldn't make any syntactical sense coming after `var` in JavaScript. Only `document.write()` or `document.createElement('script')` is going to allow the JavaScript to introduce new JavaScript.

Comment: I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding here about how `echo` works. `echo` is a *server side* operation. An `echo` *cannot, will not* ever happen after someone clicks on something in their web browser. All `echo`s will have already occurred on the server side before the web browser every gets a chance to respond to a click. By time the user clicks on something, it's too late for `echo` to do anything any more.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I'ma go back to the drawing board and see what I can do. Thank you for your help :)